# How to resolve gcc bootstrap error "Where has __float 128 gone?"

Tags: gcc, patch, configure

I am trying to install gcc 4.7.3 or greater. The specs of my machine are as follows.

- OS X 10.8.4
- Darwin 12.4.0
- gcc 4.2.1, configured with:

  ```
  --disable-checking
  --enable-werror
  --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2
  --mandir=/share/man
  --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++
  --program-prefix=llvm-
  --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/
  --with-slibdir=/usr/lib
  --build=i686-apple-darwin11
  --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~28/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local
  --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11-
  --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11
  --target=i686-apple-darwin11
  --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
  ```

I have performed the following steps thus far.

```
$ tar zxf gcc-4.7.3.tar.gz
$ mkdir objdir4.7.3
$ cd objdir4.7.3
$ /Users/DJ/gcc-4.7.3/configure
$ make bootstrap
```

This produces the following error

```
In file included from ./kinds.h:75:0,
             from /Users/DJ/scratch/gcc-4.7.3/libgfortran/libgfortran.h:232,
             from /Users/DJ/scratch/gcc-4.7.3/libgfortran/fmain.c:4:
/Users/DJ/scratch/gcc-4.7.3/libgfortran/kinds-override.h:40:5: error: #error "Where has __float128 gone?"
make[3]: *** [fmain.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-target-libgfortran] Error 2
make: *** [bootstrap] Error 2
```

I have tried implementing the fix found here: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53731

I implemented this fix by first deleting everything in the `objdir4.7.3` directory and then modifying `.../gcc-4.7.3/Makefile.in` and `.../gcc-4.7.3/Makfile.tpl` as described in the fix. The fix required adding `(MULTISUBDIR)` in one place in each file. I saved these changes as a pathed version in a new directory called `.../gcc-4.7.3_patched`.

I `cd`'ed into the `objdir4.7.3` directory once more and then ran the configure script in the pathed directory. The `make bootstrap` step created the same error.

---

Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. I have tried to be as descriptive as possible. If the error is mine, hopefully someone can spot it. Otherwise, perhaps someone with more knowledge can help me solve this problem.

Comment: This needs to be fixed. This is ridiculous.